# Проблема с циклами и клеточным игровым полем

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Недавно я создал код, который бы генерировал поле 50x50 клеток. Выглядело это примерно так:

```js
var grid_tmp_pos = 0;
var grid_config = {
  g_width: 50,
  g_height: 50
};
var grid_state = '';
for (i = 1; i <= grid_config.g_height; i++) {
  for (o = 1; o <= grid_config.g_width + 1; o++) {
    if (o > grid_config.g_width) {
      document.getElementById("gamefield").innerHTML = grid_state + '<br>';
      grid_state = document.getElementById("gamefield").innerHTML;
      grid_tmp_pos += (o - 1);
    } else {
      /*Настройки клетки*/
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="gamefield"></div>
```

Проблема лишь была в том, что при использовании двойного цикла(и без него) прогрузка занимала около 10 секунд. Есть ли способ избежать медленной работы программы?

Comment: а что такое у вас эти клетки? если сниппет выполнить, то во первых, ничего не показывается в нем, во вторых это происходит быстро, так что проблема видимо в ваших Настройках клетки и отрисовке браузером.

Comment: в любом случае, для отображаения добавьте вы туда w*h клеток (хз допустим в виде `span` они у вас) и для `nth-child(50n)` к примеру `clear:right` делайте

Comment: @teran, <span> inline-block, 50 width, 50 height. Также вносится методом push в массив с данными клетки(tiles)

Comment: @YaroslavSventsitskiy это мы должны вообразить в нашем мозгу?

Comment: Я один не понимаю что тут происходит? Не понимаю в чем вообще задумка ... `o <= grid_config.g_width + 1; o++` ... `if (o > grid_config.g_width)` - так и должно быть?